# Text comparison by excluding array values

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

```
function htmlDiff($old, $new)
{
$ret = '';
$diff = diff(explode(' ', $old), explode(' ', $new));
foreach($diff as $k)
{
    if(is_array($k))
    {

        $ret .= (!empty($k['d'])?"<del style='background:#FFFF00;'>".implode(' ',$k['d'])."</del> ":'').    (!empty($k['i'])?"<ins style='background:#00FF00;'>".implode(' ',$k['i'])."</ins> ":'');
    }
    else $ret .= $k . ' ';
}
return $ret;
 }
function diff($old, $new)
 {
$maxlen = 0;

foreach($old as $oindex => $ovalue)
{
    $nkeys = array_keys($new, $ovalue);
    foreach($nkeys as $nindex)
    {

        $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ? $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
        if($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen)
        {
            $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
            $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
            $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
        }
    }
}

if($maxlen == 0) return array(array('d'=>$old, 'i'=>$new));
    return array_merge(
diff(array_slice($old, 0, $omax), array_slice($new, 0, $nmax)),
array_slice($new, $nmax, $maxlen),
diff(array_slice($old, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($new, $nmax + $maxlen)));
    }
```

From the above text comparison function how to exclude some array values.For eg: I need to compare the two text with htmlDiff("combined and long","combined text and long text") by  excluding the  array("and","have","as soon as").

Comment: Might want to tag this as a PHP question

Comment: You tried to do that with in_array() method ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$arr = array("and", "have");
if(!in_array($yourVar, $arr)) {
  .. compare
}
```

Comment: where can I put the above code.can u please clarify with full code.

Comment: .Result should be the whole text with out highlighting the array values(ins or del).

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to understand how matrix comparison exactly works.. but I suppose something like this

```
function htmlDiff($old, $new, $exceptions = array()) {
    $ret = '';
    $diff = diff(explode(' ', $old), explode(' ', $new), $exceptions);
    foreach ($diff as $k) {
        if (is_array($k)) {

            $ret .= (!empty($k['d']) ? "<del style='background:#FFFF00;'>" . implode(' ', $k['d']) . "</del> " : '') . (!empty($k['i']) ? "<ins style='background:#00FF00;'>" . implode(' ', $k['i']) . "</ins> " : '');
        }
        else {
            $ret .= $k . ' ';
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function diff($old, $new, $exceptions = array()) {
    $maxlen = 0;

    foreach ($old as $oindex => $ovalue) {
        $nkeys = array_keys($new, $ovalue);
        foreach ($nkeys as $nindex) {
            $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) && in_array($ovalue, $exceptions) ? $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
            if ($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen) {
                $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
                $omax   = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
                $nmax   = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($maxlen == 0) {
        return array(
            array(
                'd'=> $old,
                'i'=> $new
            )
        );
    }
    return array_merge(
        diff(array_slice($old, 0, $omax), array_slice($new, 0, $nmax)),
        array_slice($new, $nmax, $maxlen),
        diff(array_slice($old, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($new, $nmax + $maxlen)));
}
```

Comment: my idea is find out the ins tags and del tags and replace array value  with "</ins>some value <ins>" or "</del>some value</del>".  How to get all <ins> tags and replace specific word inside the tags using the array.?